# Cannot understand numpy argpartition output

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to use arpgpartition from numpy, but it seems there is something going wrong and I cannot seem to figure it out. Here is what's happening:

These are first 5 elements of the sorted array `norms`

```
np.sort(norms)[:5]
array([ 53.64759445,  54.91434479,  60.11617279,  64.09630585,  64.75318909], dtype=float32)
```

But when I use `indices_sorted = np.argpartition(norms, 5)[:5]`

```
norms[indices_sorted]
array([ 60.11617279,  64.09630585,  53.64759445,  54.91434479,  64.75318909], dtype=float32)
```

When I think I should get the same result as the sorted array?

It works just fine when I use 3 as the parameter `indices_sorted = np.argpartition(norms, 3)[:3]`

```
norms[indices_sorted]
array([ 53.64759445,  54.91434479,  60.11617279], dtype=float32)
```

This isn't making much sense to me, hoping someone can offer some insight?

EDIT: Rephrasing this question as whether argpartition preserves order of the k partitioned elements makes more sense.

Comment: "When I think I should get the same result as the sorted array?" - no, that's not how `argpartition` works at all. Go read the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) again. `argpartition` makes no promises about the order of elements within a partition.

Comment: The "in partitioned order" of the docs may be a bit confusing. `argpartition` and `partition` do only split the operand into the bottom k elements and the rest. How the individual groups are ordered is undefined. Otherwise these functions couldn't work with guaranteed O(n).

Comment: So I am guessing using `argsort` over `argpartiton` to do the same task would only be slower, but that the order would be guaranteed?

Comment: Yes. If you only need the _k_ lowest you can first argpartition to get them then argsort only those. You'd have to translate the indices afterwards, though. Anyway, that would be O(n + k log k) as opposed to O(n log n) for direct argsort.

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up for!

Comment: The doc of this function is so hard to understand. I am still unclear, what the function does. And the examples are unexplained useless.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

We need to use list of indices that are to be kept in sorted order instead of feeding the kth param as a scalar. Thus, to maintain the sorted nature across the first `5` elements, instead of `np.argpartition(a,5)[:5]`, simply do -

```
np.argpartition(a,range(5))[:5]
```

Here's a sample run to make things clear -

```
In [84]: a = np.random.rand(10)

In [85]: a
Out[85]: 
array([ 0.85017222,  0.19406266,  0.7879974 ,  0.40444978,  0.46057793,
        0.51428578,  0.03419694,  0.47708   ,  0.73924536,  0.14437159])

In [86]: a[np.argpartition(a,5)[:5]]
Out[86]: array([ 0.19406266,  0.14437159,  0.03419694,  0.40444978,  0.46057793])

In [87]: a[np.argpartition(a,range(5))[:5]]
Out[87]: array([ 0.03419694,  0.14437159,  0.19406266,  0.40444978,  0.46057793])
```

Please note that `argpartition` makes sense on performance aspect, if we are looking to get sorted indices for a small subset of elements, let's say `k` number of elems which is  a small fraction of the total number of elems.

Let's use a bigger dataset and try to get sorted indices for all elems to make the above mentioned point clear -

```
In [51]: a = np.random.rand(10000)*100

In [52]: %timeit np.argpartition(a,range(a.size-1))[:5]
10 loops, best of 3: 105 ms per loop

In [53]: %timeit a.argsort()
1000 loops, best of 3: 893 µs per loop
```

Thus, to sort all elems, `np.argpartition` isn't the way to go.

Now, let's say I want to get sorted indices for only the first 5 elems with that big dataset and also keep the order for those -

```
In [68]: a = np.random.rand(10000)*100

In [69]: np.argpartition(a,range(5))[:5]
Out[69]: array([1647,  942, 2167, 1371, 2571])

In [70]: a.argsort()[:5]
Out[70]: array([1647,  942, 2167, 1371, 2571])

In [71]: %timeit np.argpartition(a,range(5))[:5]
10000 loops, best of 3: 112 µs per loop

In [72]: %timeit a.argsort()[:5]
1000 loops, best of 3: 888 µs per loop
```

Very useful here!

Answer (score 13):

Given the task of indirectly sorting a subset (the top *k*, top meaning first in sort order) there are two builtin solutions: `argsort` and `argpartition` cf. @Divakar's answer.

If, however, performance is a consideration then it may (depending on the sizes of the data and the subset of interest) be well worth resisting the "lure of the one-liner", investing one more line and applying `argsort` on the output of `argpartition`:

```
>>> def top_k_sort(a, k):
...     return np.argsort(a)[:k]
...
>>> def top_k_argp(a, k):
...     return np.argpartition(a, range(k))[:k]
...
>>> def top_k_hybrid(a, k):
...     b = np.argpartition(a, k)[:k]
...     return b[np.argsort(a[b])]

>>> k = 100
>>> timeit.timeit('f(a,k)', 'a=rng((100000,))', number = 1000, globals={'f': top_k_sort, 'rng': np.random.random, 'k': k})
8.348663672804832
>>> timeit.timeit('f(a,k)', 'a=rng((100000,))', number = 1000, globals={'f': top_k_argp, 'rng': np.random.random, 'k': k})
9.869098862167448
>>> timeit.timeit('f(a,k)', 'a=rng((100000,))', number = 1000, globals={'f': top_k_hybrid, 'rng': np.random.random, 'k': k})
1.2305558240041137
```

`argsort` is O(n log n), `argpartition` with range argument appears to be O(nk) (?), and `argpartition` + `argsort` is O(n + k log k)

Therefore in an interesting regime *n* >> *k* >> 1 the hybrid method is expected to be fastest

UPDATE: ND version:

```
import numpy as np
from timeit import timeit

def top_k_sort(A,k,axis=-1):
    return A.argsort(axis=axis)[(*axis%A.ndim*(slice(None),),slice(k))]

def top_k_partition(A,k,axis=-1):
    return A.argpartition(range(k),axis=axis)[(*axis%A.ndim*(slice(None),),slice(k))]

def top_k_hybrid(A,k,axis=-1):
    B = A.argpartition(k,axis=axis)[(*axis%A.ndim*(slice(None),),slice(k))]
    return np.take_along_axis(B,np.take_along_axis(A,B,axis).argsort(axis),axis)

A = np.random.random((100,10000))
k = 100

from timeit import timeit

for f in globals().copy():
    if f.startswith("top_"):
        print(f, timeit(f"{f}(A,k)",globals=globals(),number=10)*100)
```

Sample run:

```
top_k_sort 63.72379460372031
top_k_partition 99.30561298970133
top_k_hybrid 10.714635509066284
```

Comment: Note that if this is to be applied to multidimensional arrays (e.g. sorting the columns of rows), the indexing at the end in top_k_hybrid doesn't work, and I haven't found a reasonable solution for it. But in my timing test for 2 dims even adding an argsort without the indexing is slower than using a range, so I'd recommend this (in this case the top k, so it's a negative range, and flipped columns):
`np.argpartition(matrix, range(-k, 0), axis=1)[:, ::-1]`

Answer (score 13):

Let's describe the **partition** method in a simplified way which helps a lot understand **argpartition**

[image]

Following the example in the picture if we execute **C=numpy.argpartition(A, 3)** C will be the resulting array of getting the position of every element in B with respect to the A array. ie:

```
Idx(z) = index of element z in array A

then C would be

C = [ Idx(B[0]), Idx(B[1]), Idx(B[2]), Idx(X), Idx(B[4]), ..... Idx(B[N]) ]
```

As previously mentioned this method is very helpful and comes very handy when you have a huge array and you are only interested in a selected group of ordered elements, not the whole array.