# How to get indexes of k maximum values from a numpy multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy

I went through several questions on `StackOverflow` but could not find the relevant answer. I want to fetch indices of k maximum values from a `numpy` `ndarray`. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910641/how-to-get-indices-of-n-maximum-values-in-a-numpy-array) discusses the same but for 1D array. `np.argsort` for 2D array resulted into sorting of elements row-wise . i.e

```
Note: array elements are not unique.
```

input:

```
import numpy as np
n = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
>>> n
array([[0, 1, 2],
   [3, 4, 5],
   [6, 7, 8]])
s = n.argsort()
>>> s
array([[0, 1, 2],
   [0, 1, 2],
   [0, 1, 2]], dtype=int32)
```

Also,

```
import numpy as np
n = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
s = n.argsort(axis=None)
>>>s
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=int32)
```

but I am loosing the array structure here and can not redeem the original indices of the elements.

Any knid of help is appreciated.

Comment: do you want an answer for 2D arrays of for nD arrays where n > 2?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Couple of approaches with [`np.argpartition`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) and [`np.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) for ndarrays -

```
def k_largest_index_argpartition_v1(a, k):
    idx = np.argpartition(-a.ravel(),k)[:k]
    return np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(idx, a.shape))

def k_largest_index_argpartition_v2(a, k):
    idx = np.argpartition(a.ravel(),a.size-k)[-k:]
    return np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(idx, a.shape))

def k_largest_index_argsort(a, k):
    idx = np.argsort(a.ravel())[:-k-1:-1]
    return np.column_stack(np.unravel_index(idx, a.shape))
```

**Discussion on two versions with `argpartition`**

Difference between `k_largest_index_argpartition_v1` and `k_largest_index_argpartition_v2` is how we are using `argparition`. In the first version, we are negating input array and then using `argpartition` to get the indices for the smallest `k` indices, thus effectively getting the largest `k` indices, whereas in the second version, we are getting the first `a.size-k` smallest indices and then we are choosing the leftover largest `k` indices.

Also, its worth mentioning here that with `argpartition`, we are not getting the indices in their sorted order. If the sorted order is needed, we need to feed in range array to `np.argpartition`, as mentioned in this [`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42875652/3293881).

Sample runs -

1) 2D case :

```
In [42]: a    # 2D array
Out[42]: 
array([[38, 14, 81, 50],
       [17, 65, 60, 24],
       [64, 73, 25, 95]])

In [43]: k_largest_index_argsort(a, k=2)
Out[43]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [0, 2]])

In [44]: k_largest_index_argsort(a, k=4)
Out[44]: 
array([[2, 3],
       [0, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [1, 1]])

In [66]: k_largest_index_argpartition_v1(a, k=4)
Out[66]: 
array([[2, 1], # Notice the order is different
       [2, 3],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 1]])
```

2) 3D case :

```
In [46]: a # 3D array
Out[46]: 
array([[[20, 98, 27, 73],
        [33, 78, 48, 59],
        [28, 91, 64, 70]],

       [[47, 34, 51, 19],
        [73, 38, 63, 94],
        [95, 25, 93, 64]]])

In [47]: k_largest_index_argsort(a, k=2)
Out[47]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 0]])
```

Runtime test -

```
In [56]: a = np.random.randint(0,99999999999999,(3000,4000))

In [57]: %timeit k_largest_index_argsort(a, k=10)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.18 s per loop

In [58]: %timeit k_largest_index_argpartition_v1(a, k=10)
10 loops, best of 3: 178 ms per loop

In [59]: %timeit k_largest_index_argpartition_v2(a, k=10)
10 loops, best of 3: 128 ms per loop
```

Comment: Just for clarity, `argpartition` won't give the top `k` in order, just the top `k` in their initial order.  A way to have the best of both worlds (speed of `argpartition`, order of `argsort`) is to sort after the partition: do `idx2=np.argsort(-a.ravel()[idx])` and then `row,col = np.unravel.index(idx[idx2], a.shape)`

Comment: Well that's easier!

Comment: "As such, the first version would be better" - why does it matter whether you take the first or last `k`? Argpartition doesn't sort the first `k`, does it?

Comment: Also, the cost of doing `-a.ravel()` is somewhat significant here

Comment: In fact, for any `k not in [1,2]`, the second version is consistently faster - so you just got lucky with your choice of small `k`

Comment: @Eric Exactly, I found out something peculiar that for `k=2`, `argpartition` runtime is a small number, but for `3` onwards, it shoots up and stays more or less constant thereafter. Thus, if we do : `a = np.random.randint(0,99999999999999,(10000000))` and then `np.argpartition(a,2)` comes at `39msec`, whereas with `k=3`, gets to `90.6 ms `.

Comment: @Eric So, I made a wrong assumption there about `argpartition`, removed that part. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: This is so good, I have to cite it.  Did you want credit in any other way besides a link here?

Comment: @mLstudent33 Citation where exactly?

Comment: In my masters degree assignment so no real publicity unfortunately.  I just pasted th link directly above the code snippet where I use it.

Comment: @mLstudent33 So, what I do when I am quoting codes from elsewhere on here, I put the link and the author name with `@` on top of the function code, something like in here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/51951787/. So, I guess that could be used in assignments/outside of Stackoverflow too.