# How to find N maximum product subarrays of M elements of a Numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, sub-array

I have a Numpy array, and I need to find the N maximum product subarrays of M elements. For example, I have the array `p = [0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.3, 0.5]` and I want to find the 5 highest product subarrays of 3 elements. Is there a "fast" way to do that?

Comment: That is not a numpy array

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Answer (score 1):

**Approach #1**

We can create sliding windows and then perform `prod` reduction and finally `np.argpartition` to get top `N` ones among them -

```
from skimage.util.shape import view_as_windows

def topN_windowed_prod(a, W, N):
    w = view_as_windows(a,W)
    return w[w.prod(1).argpartition(-N)[-N:]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [2]: p = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.3, 0.5])

In [3]: topN_windowed_prod(p, W=3, N=2)
Out[3]: 
array([[0.8, 0.5, 0.7],
       [0.5, 0.7, 0.9]])
```

Note that the order is not maintained with `np.argpartition`. So, if we need the top `N` in descending order of `prod` values, use `range(N)` with it. [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42185645/).

**Approach #2**

For smaller window lengths, we can simply slice and get our desired result, like so -

```
def topN_windowed_prod_with_slicing(a, W, N):
    w = view_as_windows(a,W)
    L = len(a)-W+1
    acc = a[:L].copy()
    for i in range(1,W):
        acc *= a[i:i+L]
    idx = acc.argpartition(-N)[-N:]
    return w[idx]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another quick way to do it:

```py
import numpy as np

p = [0.1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.5, 0.7, 0.9, 0.3, 0.5]
n = 5
m = 3

# Cumulative product (starting with 1)
pc = np.cumprod(np.r_[1, p])
# Cumulative product of each window
w = pc[m:] / pc[:-m]
# Indices of the first element of top N windows
idx = np.argpartition(w, n)[-n:]
print(idx)
# [1 2 5 4 3]
```

Comment: Idea is good. It's just that with decent sized arrays, and with fractions in it, it will end up with zeros at the backend.

Comment: @Divakar Yes, that's a good point, if the array is big enough then precision is likely to suffer, and if it is not then performance is probably not a concern anyway.