# How does Numpy's partition function work?

Tags: python, numpy, partition

I didn't understand how `numpy.partition` works. The [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html) says:

> Creates a copy of the array with its elements rearranged in such a way
>   that the value of the element in k-th position is in the position it
>   would be in a sorted array. All elements smaller than the k-th element
>   are moved before this element and all equal or greater are moved
>   behind it.

I have tried to run this code

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2, 4, 1, 5, 0])
np.partition(a,0)
```

The 0-th element of the array is 2, so I would expect the resulting array to be made as following: all elements *smaller than* 2 to the left of it, and all elements *greater than* 2 to the right of it.

Instead I get the following result:

```
array([0, 4, 1, 5, 2])
```

where 2 is in the last position.

How is this result justified given the documentation?

Can you provide a step-by-step example of what this `np.partition` does?

Comment: Your interpretation is wrong. Smallest K elements would be in the first K positions in the output, while the rest in the remaining len(array)-K positions. Your statement/interpretation starts with `The 0-th element of the array is 2,..`, which sounds like you are trying to do something else.

Comment: @Divakar thank you. Can you provide an example of how does the function works? The documentation says "the element in the k-th position", what is the correct interpretation?

Comment: It's right there. `Creates a copy of the array with its elements rearranged in such a way that the value of the element in k-th position`. They are talking about the `k-th position` in the **output, not the input**.

Comment: Can I have in a reply a step-by-step example of what this function does, please?

Comment: The key is that ``k`` refers to the ``k``th element *after partitioning*.

Comment: This did a good job on it - https://stackoverflow.com/a/61194012/.