# Getting wrong results with np.argpartition, while selecting maximum n values from an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, numpy-slicing

so I was using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23734295/12705907) answer on 'How do I get indices of N maximum values in a NumPy array?' question. I used it in my ML model in which it outputs Logsoftmax layer values and I was thinking to get top 4 classes in each. In most of the cases, it sorted and gave values correctly but in a very few cases, I see partially unsorted results like this

```
arr = np.array([-3.0302, -2.7103, -7.4844, -3.4761, -5.3009, -5.2121, -3.7549, -4.7834,
     -5.8870, -3.4839, -5.0104, -3.0992, -4.8823, -0.3319, -6.8084])
ind = np.argpartition(arr, -4)[-4:]
print(arr[ind])
```

and the output is

```
[-3.0992 -3.0302 -0.3319 -2.7103]
```

which is unsorted, it has to output the maximum values at last but it is not seen in this case. I checked with other examples and it is doing all fine. Like

```
arr = np.array([45, 35, 67.345, -34.5555, 66, -0.23655, 11.0001, 0.234444444])
ind = np.argpartition(arr, -4)[-4:]
print(arr[ind])
```

output

```
[35.    45.    66.    67.345]
```

What could be the reason? Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not planning on actually utilizing the sorted indices, why not just use [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html)?

```
>>> arr = np.array([-3.0302, -2.7103, -7.4844, -3.4761, -5.3009, -5.2121, -3.7549, 
              -4.7834, -5.8870, -3.4839, -5.0104, -3.0992, -4.8823, -0.3319, -6.8084])

>>> np.sort(arr)[-4:]
array([-3.0992, -3.0302, -2.7103, -0.3319])
```

---

Alternatively, [as read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42184499/cannot-understand-numpy-argpartition-output) you could use a `range` for your `kth` option on [`np.argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
np.argpartition(arr, range(0, -4, -1))[-4:]
array([-3.0992, -3.0302, -2.7103, -0.3319])
```

Comment: Hey, sorry that I didn't mention this. I am actually planning to use the sorted indices as well to map with the array of class names associated with it. Finally I am printing the top k classified classes with scores. 
Example output: Dog: -0.3319    Cat: -2.7103    Cow: -3.0302
So I need indices along with values.